# Using IntellijIdea within an existing virtualenv

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, virtualenv, pycharm

I want to use Intellij Idea within my existing python django project which was built within a virtual environment in ubuntu. How do I configure Intellij Idea to use the libraries of the virtual environment?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

#### For PyCharm 2018

As per [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) from Pycharm:

1. In the Project Interpreter page, click [image: ]] and select Add.
2. In the left-hand pane of the Add Python Interpreter dialog box, select Virtualenv Environment. The following actions depend on whether
   the virtual environment existed before.
3. If Existing environment is selected:

   1. Specify the required interpreter: use the drop-down list, or click Select an interpreter and find one in your file system.
   2. Select the check-box Make available to all projects, if needed.
4. Click OK to complete the task.

---

#### For Pycharm 2016 and later

To add an existing virtual environment to the list of available interpreters

1. In the Project Interpreter page, click [image].
2. In the drop-down list, choose **Add local**.

[image: add environment option]

3. In the Select Python Interpreter dialog box that opens, choose the desired Python executable, located inside the virtual environment folder, and click **OK**.

Go to this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) for more information.

---

#### For Older versions:

Well I solved the above problem. I have added virtualenv folder's python to project sdk. The virtualenv directory's python( for example venv/bin/python2.7) needs to be added to Intellij Idea project path. Example: need to go to file>project structure (intellij Idea)
[image]

press new in **Project SDK**, and add new path to virtualenv's python directory like this:[image]

Go to Modules>Dependencies and set your module sdk to Python SDK which is marked on this picture: [image]

Click on **Django** (option marked in next the image) and set `Django project root`, `Settings`,`Manage Script` like this:[image]

Now press ok and final look of the Project settings: [image]

Now need to run the project.

Comment: this page describes how to add an existing pythong virtualenv
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html

however, on OSX, it opens a file dialog, and it doesn't allow to navigate to "hidden" dirs, such as the typical ~/.virtualenvs

any idea?

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstood: actually they don't show the hidden directory in the file browser, but if you type the directory name, then type `/` it will take you inside the hidden folder. It worked for me in 2016 versions. Haven't tested in 2017 edition. Directly copy pasting the path of the python file ie `/home/user/proj/.env/bin/python` in the file browser also works. @DavidPortabella

Comment: it works, thx! when the file dialog appears, typing / will prompt for the path.
here it also explains that you can use Command-Shift-. to show hidden files, and Command-Shift-G as an alternative to typing /.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205435510
http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/01/show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-dialog-boxes-with-commandshiftperiod/

Comment: For IntelliJ, when using `Existing Environment` option, make sure you have to select `[...]/venv/bin/python` (not simply `[...]/venv/`)

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is based on older version of IntelliJ. For new, look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html