# pycharm django super().get_context_data(**kwargs) has errors

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

This is my code I'm trying to:

```
class PublisherDetail(SingleObjectMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    template_name = "books/publisher_detail.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object(queryset=Publisher.objects.all())
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['publisher'] = self.object
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.object.book_set.all()
```

in this line:

```
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Pycharm says:
    python version 2.7 does not support this syntax.
P.S:
1) Setting > Editor > Inspection > Code compatibility is disabled
2) My interpreter is python 3.6.3

and the second error is about (in the same line):

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'get_context_data' for class 'super'
```

P.S:
I have marked source root in Pycharm.

How can I get rid of these errors? (both are errors, not warnings)

Pycharm version: 
PyCharm 2018.2.3 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-182.4323.49, built on September 4, 2018
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: I forgot to say, It's working fine when I runserver, but in Pycharm it has errors.

Comment: check what interpreter setting contains python version?

Comment: @ManojJadhav Thanks for your comment. It's 3.6.3

Comment: @Amin.B maybe you can look into this anwer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20879661/2696165 for configuring Python in Pycharm

Comment: @ruddra Thanks, I double checked and there was no problem.

Comment: Are you sure that in `settings -> project -> project interpreter` you've set Python3?

Comment: @Satevg yes, I could solve the problem by just restarting the Pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. Just close and open Pycharm (restart). That was so weird.
You can also use: **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart**